# Java: Time in milliseconds to HTTP format?

Tags: java, http, date

I have a File object and I want to get the last modified date of that file into [HTTP format](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html).
The format is in GMT time and is like:

```
Mon, 10 Feb 2014 16:17:37 GMT
```

I know [java.io.File](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html) has a method [`lastModified()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#lastModified%28%29) which returns the time in milliseconds. I can also pass that time in milliseconds to the constructor of the [java.util.Date](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) class. But what is the easiest way to get a string in HTTP format?

Thanks.

Comment: See if the following helps:  http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/04/how-to-convert-local-time-to-gmt-in.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = 
  new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z", Locale.US);
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
String httpDate = sdf.format(new Date(file.lastModified()));
```

Answer (score 5):

## java.time

Read the below `Joda-Time` section for details. The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) (up to nine (9) digits of a decimal fraction).

```
long milliseconds = … ; 
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli( milliseconds );  // Or use Instant.now() to experiment.
```

For formatting, convert to `OffsetDateTime`.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = instant.atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC );
```

The [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html?is-external=true) class provides a [ready-made formatter for your desired format](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#RFC_1123_DATE_TIME). That format is defined by the [RFC 1123](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1123) standard.

```
String output = odt.format ( DateTimeFormatter.RFC_1123_DATE_TIME );
```

> Wed, 11 Jan 2017 21:35:19 GMT

With other formatters, I would say to always specify the `Locale`. But that particular formatter for RFC 1123 is hard-coded to English per the RFC requirements. So specifying a `Locale` has no effect on the output.

---

## Joda-Time

Just for the heck of it, here's the same kind of code from [the correct answer by Meno Hochschild](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21682622/642706) but using the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) 2.3 library.

A couple notes…

- In date-time work, the milliseconds number must be a `long` not `int` (64-bit vs 32-bit).
- The HTTP spec requires the use of English for name of day and month. So we should specify English explicitly in case our code ever runs on a JVM where English is not the default Locale.

### Sample Code

```
 // Note how the variable for milliseconds is a "long" not "int".
long milliseconds = DateTime.now().getMillis(); // Get milliseconds from java.io.File method "lastModified", or wherever.

DateTime dateTime = new DateTime( milliseconds, DateTimeZone.UTC );
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern( "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'" ).withZone( DateTimeZone.UTC ).withLocale( java.util.Locale.ENGLISH );

String httpDateTime = formatter.print( dateTime );
```

Dump to console…

```
System.out.println( "milliseconds: " + milliseconds );
System.out.println( "dateTime: " + dateTime );
System.out.println( "httpDateTime: " + httpDateTime );
```

When run…

```
milliseconds: 1392075528617
dateTime: 2014-02-10T23:38:48.617Z
httpDateTime: Mon, 10 Feb 2014 23:38:48 GMT
```

## ISO 8601

That format is indeed required by the [HTTP 1.1 spec](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html). So if you need it, use it. But know that the Internet community has largely moved to using the more sensible [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format for the current generation of protocols. The ISO format is `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.ssssss+00:00`, as seen in second line of output above. The Joda-Time library uses ISO 8601 as its defaults for most purposes.